# Flutter: Install different versions of dependency for each platform (iOS and Android)

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm trying to install the flutter_blue dependency for bluetooth in flutter, and have realized that in my environment only version 0.6.2 works for android and version ^0.6.3+1 for ios.

Is there a way to declare a dependency or version that is platform-specific?

Answer (score 4):

I'm facing the same issue, and ended up doing the following :

1. Creating a dedicated pubspec for iOS named pubspec.ios.yaml. You can then put anything specific to iOS here:

   ```
   ...
   dependencies:
     flutter:
       sdk: flutter
     flutter_blue: 0.6.3+1
   ...
   ```
2. Adding a small script in my build pipeline:

   ```
   # We use a specific pubspec file for iOS
   cp pubspec.ios.yaml pubspec.yaml
   flutter pub get
   ```

Note that "flutter pub get" is required to re-generate pubspec.lock.

It is a bit dirty, but I did not come up with anything cleaner than that.

PS: I'm using Microsoft App Center for CI/CD, so the above was added to appcenter-post-clone.sh script just before the call to flutter build

```
# We use a specific pubspec file for iOS
cp pubspec.ios.yaml pubspec.yaml
flutter pub get

# The build !
flutter build ios --release --no-codesign -vvv
```

Comment: Note also that Flutter Blue on iOS with version ^0.6.3+1 requires ObjC support.
1. Delete ios folder in your project
2. Recreate it using : flutter create -i objc --project-name <project_name> .
Source : https://github.com/pauldemarco/flutter_blue/issues/406#issuecomment-548181411

Comment: Can someone provide any thoughts on this.. would be helpful..